# Return value from comparator using lambda expression java

Tags: java, haskell, lambda, comparator

I'm emulating the haskell function `foldl` in java.
that at the same time retrieves and removes the first index of a list. 
I've done that, with the following signature `foldl(BiFunction <R, T, R> f, R z, List<T> l)`, where `T` is a `String` and `R` a `int`.

The only problem now is I need to create a `max` java method that uses the emulated `foldl` and has the following signature: `max(Comparator<T> c, List<T> l)`.

This is the comparator I'm using as an example:
`Comparator.comparing(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.split(",")[1]));`

I figured I needed to construct a lambda expression so it returns the value of comparator if it's true.

All of my attempts were in vain, since I don't know how to use comparators in lambda expressions, and I'm newbie in this kind of expressions.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Can you explain what `foldl` does, and give some examples of input and output of your `max` method?

Comment: In addition, what the `R` and `T` types bind to, and how you intend to guarantee that `s` is a `String` would be interesting.

Comment: What do you mean by "uses the emulated `foldl`" and by "_gets_ a `Comparator` and a `List<T>`"?

Comment: @PaulBoddington I edited the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I edited the question, also I don't need to guarantee the the types, it's an exercise so we assume it's a string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom What I mean by "uses the emulated `foldl`" is that the `max` method calls the `foldl` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the maximum of two elements using a `Comparator` by doing

```
(t, u) -> c.compare(t, u) > 0 ? t : u
```

This says: if `t` is greater than `u`, return `t`, else return `u`.

This lambda expression can be passed as the `BiFunction` in your `foldl` method. Here is a full, working example. I decided to pass the first element of the list as `z`. This makes sense, as an empty list doesn't have a maximum anyway.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 5);
    System.out.println(max(Comparator.naturalOrder(), list));
}

// Not knowing Haskell at all, this is my guess at what foldl does.
private static <R, T> R foldl(BiFunction<R, T, R> f, R z, List<T> l) {
    for (T t : l)
        z = f.apply(z, t);
    return z;
}

private static <T> T max(Comparator<T> c, List<T> l) {
    if (l.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return foldl((t, u) -> c.compare(t, u) > 0 ? t : u, l.get(0), l);
}
```

In java 8, streams were introduced. This kind of process is called a reduction in java, and there are standard methods available for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks very much Paul Boddington, foldl is pretty much it, the only difference is that it removes the first element of the list, but no need to edit the answer, explained it just for you to know, I missed the `(t, u) ->` part in my attempts, now I understand how it should be done and may continue to do the rest of the exercise.
Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.